# IE delete spaces and return php errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, internet-explorer

I've got some problem with IE that bother me very much.

The url is: http://dinhjalp.com/index.php/start/montering and the errors will be seen when you click on the image-icons on the right side of the page below the text `Bildexempel`.

If you visit this site and click on the icons in firefox and chrome everything is okey, but if you visit the site in IE you'll see two kind of problems.

The first one is that IE delete spaces and swedish letters like ÅÄÖ. And if you click on the icons on the second line, (icon 3 and four) you'll get a

```
     `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE error`
```

But not in Firefox or chrome.  Is that a problem in IE or the PHP code or the Javascript-code?

And yepp, i've tested in safari and opera - no problems with this browsers. The site is build on Codeigniter. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: try html encoding those image urls.  the good browsers are probably just compensating for you.

Comment: Yepp - thank u - how could i missed that.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Image urls should be encoded,atleast when there is a browser like IE.Firefox and Chrome are just ignoring it.